# how to make the choices be near to the title?

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I'm making a latex slideshow. 
I want to let the four choices be near to the title. It means that I don't want any gap between the question and the choices.

How can I achieve that?

Be grateful with any hints!

```
\begin{frame}{1.Suppose set$M=\{x|x^2+2x=0,x\in R\}$, $N=\{x|x^2-2x=0,x\in R\}$,then$M\cup N=(~)$}
  \begin{columns}[t]%
    \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
          \begin{itemize}
        \item A.~~$\{0\}$
        \item B.~~$\{0,2\}$
      \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
     \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
         \begin{itemize}
        \item C.~~$\{-2,0\}$
        \item D.~~$\{-2,0,2\}$
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just use \begin{frame}[t] ... \end{frame}.

Comment: @Jesse thanks for your reply. It works! But it is not near enough, some gap still exist.

Comment: OK, add an extra command \vspace{-0.5cm} right before \begin{columns} .

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino -- It is done. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Beamer frame` provides `[tcb]`, t=top, c=center(default), b=bottom for text alignment. Since your OP did not provide such information. The text will be centered by default which is what you get in the OP. If wanting to reduce more spaces, `\vspace{<negative dimension>}` can be used for fine tune.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{1.Suppose set$M=\{x|x^2+2x=0,x\in R\}$, $N=\{x|x^2-2x=0,x\in R\}$,then$M\cup N=(~)$}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
  \begin{columns}[t]%
    \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
          \begin{itemize}
        \item A.~~$\{0\}$
        \item B.~~$\{0,2\}$
      \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
     \begin{column}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
         \begin{itemize}
        \item C.~~$\{-2,0\}$
        \item D.~~$\{-2,0,2\}$
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```